# Inverse operator: what does it mean in Banach spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, fourier-transform

If one is dealing with sets, given a function $f:A \to B$, its inverse is a function $g:B \to A$ such that $f \circ g= id_B$ and $g \circ f= id_A$. This carries over to linear functions defined on finite dimensional vector spaces, too. But let's take a continuous linear operator from a Banach space to another,for instance the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$. It is known that $\mathcal{F}$ maps $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ into $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ (thanks to Plancherel's theorem) and it is trivial to verify its boundedness from $L^1$ to $L^\infty$. Thanks to interpolation, one can thus say that $\mathcal{F}: L^p \to L^q$ continuously with $p \in [1,2]$ and $q \in [2, + \infty]$ its Holder conjugate.

To define the Fourier transform "directly", one should need $f \in L^1$, but thanks to continuity I should be able to work on a dense and "nice" subset of $L^p$ where everything works and then define the Fourier transform of a function $f \in L^p$ approximating $f$ with "nice" function, defining the $\mathcal{F}$ as a limit.

The class of "nice" dense function that I am going to take is the Schwartz functions, that is "rapidly decreasing" smooth functions $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. It can be proved that $\mathcal{F}: \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{S}$ continuously, and that $\mathcal{S}$ is dense in $L^p$ with $p \in [1, \infty)$. Now, if I understood well, you can define the Fourier transform on every $L^p$ with $1\leq p< \infty$, but you have to take the codomain in a way that gives you continuity of the operator. So, to sum up, given $f \in L^p$ with $p \in [1,2]$:

$$\mathcal{F}(f)= \lim_n \mathcal{F}(f_n) \; \text{ that converge in } L^q$$

with $f_n \in \mathcal{S}$. If $p >2$, theory of distributions comes up, and I should only have that $\mathcal{F}: L^p \to \mathcal{S}'$.

Let's say that I want to invert the Fourier transform. If I work with $\mathcal{S}$ everything works fine, but if I consider $\mathcal{F}: L^p \to L^q$, (with $p\in [1,2]$ and $q \in  [2, \infty]$) using the classical insiemistic definition of "inverse" would lead me to search for an operator from $L^q$ to $L^p$, and this shouldn't work, because $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ should be well defined only if its codomain is the tempered distributions, that is not every function in $L^q$ has an inverse Fourier transform that is still a function. So, what is a formal argument that puts everything in order? I feel like one should use a density argument, maybe restricting to the image of the Fourier transform, but it somehow still puzzles me a bit that if the inverse of a function from $A$ to $B$ is not a function fromm $B$ to $A$

Comment: Isn't the Inverse Function Theorem the formal argument you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think so. If I remember correctly that theorem should take into account Frechet derivatives and give sufficient conditions for obtaining a local inverse, that is in a neighborhood of the point considered. I am not sure, but I think that even if you restrict to a small ball in $L^q$, the image of the ball through Fourier transform isn't fully contained in $L^p$, something goes in $\mathcal{S}'$

Comment: The Inverse Function Theorem for Banach spaces does use the Frechet derivative (e.g. http://math.mit.edu/~eyjaffe/Short%20Notes/Miscellaneous/Inverse%20Function%20Theorem.pdf )  However, the IFT is "local" in a sense: it works only in a "small enough" neighbourhood, which might not yield what you're after

Comment: I don't really follow you, but you plan on defining the IFT only on small neighborhoods of images of the Fourier transform, correct? And if you are correct, then you'd be able to define the IFT from $L^q$ to $L^p$? Seems strange